# problem on starting cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I download apache-cassandra-0.8.5 for ubuntu and extract it.I read the readme file.
I try bellow command in shell:

```
bin/cassandra -f
```

But it said:
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name 
unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: node24.nise.local: node24.nise.local

what should I do?

Comment: problem is discussed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2380

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What does your `/etc/hosts` file contain? Maybe add `localhost` and `node24.nise.local` as a name at the `127.0.0.1` line.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

Comment: Then add `node24.nise.local` to this line.

Comment: @Dunaril: please add your comment to the answer so that it is more complete.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. It works once you add domain name in local host entry `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  testdomain  localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Answer (score 8):

Add following line in the `/etc/hosts` file

```
  127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost node24.nise.local
```

Replace `node24.nise.local` with your host name.

Answer (score 5):

Go to terminal and just run:

```
$ hostname localhost
```

(or whatever is your host name)

Answer (score 4):

In AWS EC2, when you install Cassandra you can have this problem because of the initially configured hostname which is set to ip-x-x-x-x being x-x-x-x the EC2 instance private address. The steps to solve it:

1. Edit network configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/network`

   `HOSTNAME=[myservername]`
2. Edit hosts file:

   `sudo vi /etc/hosts`
3. Add hostname entry to `/etc/hosts`

   `127.0.0.1 [myservername]`
4. Set hostname or reboot

   `sudo hostname [myservername]`

Comment: thanks! I met this issue in MAC, and I followed the 4th : `sudo scutil --set HostName localhost`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the Same Issue and it is resolved by following steps.
**1.Edit the HostNames File in your Ubuntu system**
 $ sudo nano /etc/hosts
  After this add System name or Your System IP in first Name like following.
127.0.0.1       bflesgwks011 
(Or)
127.0.0.1       192.168.15.22 
**2.Save&Exit the file.**
**3.Restart the Network by using the command.**
 $ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

I hope it Works.
thanks.