# Ubuntu 12.04 and cassandra install - +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss128k

Tags: cassandra

I am following the instructions for installing cassandra at [Install Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/install_deb)

When I installed, I get the below.  How to I fix?

```
service cassandra start
xss =  -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1001M -Xmx1001M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss128k

root@i-157-16647-VM:~# service cassandra status
xss =  -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1001M -Xmx1001M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss128k
 * Cassandra is not running
```

I am running on a machine with 2 gigs of RAM.  Here is how I install on a bare bones VM.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
#add sources.list
     deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main
     deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main contrib non-free

curl -L http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-cql dsc1.1


root@i-157-16647-VM:~# java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

/var/log/cassandra/output.log
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: i-157-16647-VM: i-157-16647-VM
Service exit with a return value of 1
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: i-157-16647-VM: i-157-16647-VM
Service exit with a return value of 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: I cant get cassandra to run on a default install.  I assume issue is +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.  I cant understand that cryptic message.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. That message is just showing you the options passed to cassandra, including an option that causes it to make a heap dump if it encounters an out of memory error. What version of Java did it say you were running when you checked?

Comment: Added version. Hopefully using this was correct.  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main contrib non-free per the install docs.

Comment: Added hostname to /etc/hosts per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra

Comment: And did that fix the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running out of allocted memory for the JAVA VM (128k) is too small.

Modify the line below (..."128k"...) to reach a stack size of at least 160k in the file

`/opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh` or `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss160k"
```

Comment: On Ubuntu it's:
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

In my case doing 
sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra and
sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/log/cassandra helped to start Cassandra.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4058#comment-13662604 has more details on what could lead to this situation

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't trust [cassandra status message](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2013/10/installing-apache-cassandra/) like:

> - Cassandra is not running message

Just try

> $nodetool -h 127.0.0.1 info

Your Cassandra is maybe Ok!

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly possible due to the JDK.
I met similar error with IBM JDK, it works once I replaced the IBM JDK with Oracle JDK.