# DataStax Enterprise server won't start: dse dead but pid file exists

Tags: datastax-enterprise

When I launch it with `sudo /etc/init.d/dse start` it seems to work. It returns:

```
Starting DSE daemon dse
DSE daemon starting with Hadoop and Solr disabled (edit /etc/default/dse to enable)
```

But when I try to connect to the tutorial "Test Cluster" (so localhost) with `opscenter` (on a distant machine but with port 8888 shared), I got this error:

```
Error creating cluster: Unable to connect to cluster
```

And if I check the health of dse with `sudo /etc/init.d/dse status`: I got:

```
dse dead but pid file exists
```

Original post:

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong forum. What's the best way to migrate this  to server vault if that's the better forum? Just ask it over there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console or /var/log/cassandra/output.log will likely contain something like this (where nodename1 is whatever you named your node):

Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: nodename1: nodename1

Same as [problem on starting cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra), basically you need to make sure that the hostname you are using can be resolved (by putting it into /etc/hosts).