# Unable to start cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to start cassandra so I did 
`sudo ./cassandra`

I came across this 
`Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: node24.nise.local: node24.nise.local`

so I did what was mentioned as on [problem on starting cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra) link and i changed the /etc/hosts file.

Then the starting process got stuck after this:

```
INFO 22:27:14,227 CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='local') liveRatio is 33.904761904761905 (just-counted was 33.904761904761905).  calculation took 110ms for 3 cells

 INFO 22:27:14,260 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@726006040(84/840 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)

 INFO 22:27:14,262 Writing Memtable-local@726006040(84/2848 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)

 INFO 22:27:14,280 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-50-Data.db (116 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1401859631027, position=500327)

 WARN 22:27:14,327 setting live ratio to maximum of 64.0 instead of Infinity

 INFO 22:27:14,327 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@1689909512(10100/101000 serialized/live bytes, 259 ops)

 INFO 22:27:14,328 CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='local') liveRatio is 64.0 (just-counted was 64.0).  calculation took 0ms for 0 cells

 INFO 22:27:14,350 Writing Memtable-local@1689909512(10100/101000 serialized/live bytes, 259 ops)

 INFO 22:27:14,386 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-51-Data.db (5278 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1401859631027, position=512328)

 INFO 22:27:14,493 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
```

No other line was executed after this . Can anyone help in letting me know why did this happen exactly.

Comment: Can you see either the native server or thrift server starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after this statement

```
INFO 22:27:14,493 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
```

your server running normally, to verify do jps and check that CassandraDaemon is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error ..

you just need to do give command in command prompt

hostname localhost (or the hostname of where cassandra is running)

This believe it will solve your problem