# Error on starting cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have downloaded apcahe cassandra 3.11.1 on an amazon instance.

I run this in `cassandra/bin`:

```
sh cassandra
```

I get an error:

```
CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-30-0-229: ip-172-30-0-229: Name or service not known
```

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra)

This is the content of my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I have tried editing it and adding `ip-172-30-0-229:` in front of `127.0.0.1 localhost`, but I still get the same error.

What can I do?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210500/4940826

Answer (score 0):

Adding `127.0.1.1 ip-172-30-0-229` in /etc/hosts file fixed it.